# How can I count and print unque words in a json object using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to print the count and unique attribute for multiple json objects. My data looks like this:

```
[
      {
        "category": [
                     "Fast Food",
                      "Restaurants"
                    ]
      },
      {
          "category": [
                        "Nightlife"
                      ]
      },
      {
          "category": [
                        "Bars",
                        "American (New)",
                        "Nightlife",
                        "Lounges",
                        "Restaurants"
                      ]
      }
]
```

My problem is how can I count number of unique words in total for category. For example Restaurant occurs 2 times in total and so on. I am trying to use python for this. Help needed please

Comment: It'd be nice to see code that you've attempted

Comment: import json
from collections import Counter
with open('B:/David 239/project/category.json') as f:
    content = json.load(f)
carry =[]
for category in content: 
    crimeCategories  = json.dumps(category, category['category'], separators=(',', ': '))
    carry.append(category)    
    c = Counter(carry )
    print(c)

Comment: Comments are not for code. Please find the edit link for   the post

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `collections.Counter` :

```
from collections import Counter

json = #your json object
total = [dic['category'] for dic in json]
total = [cat for sublist in total for cat in sublist] # Flatten the list

Counter(total)
```

**Output :**

```
Counter({'American (New)': 1,
         'Bars': 1,
         'Fast Food': 1,
         'Lounges': 1,
         'Nightlife': 2,
         'Restaurants': 2})
```

Comment: this worked quite well yeah and i also added sorting feature so the result are in order. But thank you so much for your help. this worked really

Comment: You're welcome. However keep in mind that there is no order in a dicitonary ;)

Comment: yeah yeah actually i was building a classification model so wanted to extract these categories as labels